# How to load more the 10,000 images in a GridView?

Tags: android, image, file

I try to make gallery manager and load all image i've try with bitmap and picasso but when image size is more then 3000 app going to crash and in picasso showing to outofmemoryerror error 
i've increase the size this my code 
this my Manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

in my gridel file

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}
```

in my gridle.property  file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3536m
```

Now please guys can you suggest me which technology i should use and what technology the File Explores are using....

this is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<String> thhumbnail = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    getFromSdcard(new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera"));
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, thhumbnail,false));

}

public void getFromSdcard( File thumbnail)
{

    thhumbnail.clear();
    File[] listFilethumbnail;

    try {
        if (thumbnail.isDirectory()) {
            listFilethumbnail = thumbnail.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFilethumbnail.length; i++) {
                thhumbnail.add(listFilethumbnail[i].getAbsolutePath());


            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this my adpter file

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Bitmap bmp;
final int THUMBSIZE = 64;
int count=0;
int pos_path=-1;
boolean bms=false;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private static final int PADDING = 8;
public static  ArrayList<String> chekbox_array=new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> chekbox_array1=new ArrayList<>();

private static final int WIDTH = 250;
private static final int HEIGHT = 250;
private Activity mContext;
private List<String> mThumbIds;


public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> ids, boolean bm){
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    mContext = activity;
    this.mThumbIds = ids;
    this.bms=bm;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

// Will get called to provide the ID that
// is passed to OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// create a new ImageVie for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_cat_item,null);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_cat_item,null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_adapter_texxt);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_adapter_gride);
    final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box_adapter_gride);



    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    File fm=new File(mThumbIds.get(position));
    String image_name=fm.getName(),file_name=fm.getName();

    if (file_name.length() > 11)
    file_name=file_name.substring(0,11);

    textView.setText(file_name);



    Log.d("bitmap",String.valueOf(mThumbIds.get(position))+"\n");
    if (image_name.endsWith(".jpg")) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("file://"+mThumbIds.get(position)).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(imageView);

    }
    else {
    }

            if (pos_path != -1){
if (pos_path == position){
    chekbox_array.add(mThumbIds.get(position));
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
    Log.d("arraylistvaluenormal",String.valueOf(chekbox_array));
}else
checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }else
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: *in my gridel file `dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}` in my gridle.property file `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3536m`* this is obviously irrelevant when you run application on android device

Comment: So what should i do to increase the memory size and load images  for using this memory size increased a bit,Have you better solution for me

Comment: I don't know what you have already so it is impossible to give the answer ... I bet that you are using it all (GridView and loader library) wrong

Comment: now you can see the code loading with picasso

Comment: I would strongly recommend using recyclerview instead of gridview

Comment: read about `Picasso.fit()`

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues with your adapter code.

First off, you should tell Picasso to resize the image so that it won't load the full size image into device memory.

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(file)
       .resize(width, height) // scales down the image as it's being loaded resulting in less memory used
       .onlyScaleDown() // self explanatory, optional
       .fit() // optional, other options include centerCrop()/centerInside()
       .into(imageView);
```

Another issue is that you're inflating a new layout *every* time `getView` is being called. This will cause Picasso to keep a reference to the previous layout if it's still in the process of loading an image.

Typically how you would use the `convertView` is that you check if it's null and then inflate a layout file.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
     }
     // do stuff
     return convertView;
}
```

Picasso will keep a reference to the target that it's loading an image into and if there's a subsequent call to load another image into the same target then it will cancel the previous load request and continue on with the new one.

Since you're creating a new layout every time `getView` is called, Picasso will never cancel the previous request and will keep a reference to all of the views that it has queued loads into, which leads to a hefty amount of memory being used.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the thumbnail and get a big image through download

Comment: I'm using the thumbnail but it's complex to perform the other  operation because mange every time image and thumbnail also